# pyopencl kernel outputs black image

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

Why is the image coming out as black when saved? I am just beginning to learn opencl.
Without opencl, on purely CPU, the loop iterates through the matrix and uses the rgb2gray average formula to store the values in gray array.
Using windows and python 3.8

```
import pyopencl
import numpy as np
import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ocl_platforms = (platform.name for platform in pyopencl.get_platforms())
print("\n".join(ocl_platforms))
# select platform
platform = pyopencl.get_platforms()[0]
# select device
device = platform.get_devices()[0]

# create context
ctx = pyopencl.Context(devices=[device])

img = imread.imread('gigapixel.jpg')

r = np.array(img[:, :, 0], dtype=np.float32)

g = np.array(img[:, :, 1], dtype=np.float32)

b = np.array(img[:, :, 2], dtype=np.float32)
gray = np.empty_like(r)
# without gpu
for i in range(r.shape[0]):
    for j in range(r.shape[1]):
        gray[i, j] = (r[i, j] + g[i, j] + b[i, j]) / 3
plt.imshow(gray)
plt.show()
# convert to uint8
gray = np.uint8(gray)
# save image
imread.imsave('gray_cpu.jpg', gray)
```

with GPU the rest of the code is

```
gray = np.empty_like(r)
program_source = """
__kernel void rgb2gray(__global float *r, __global float *g, __global float *b, __global 
float *gray) {
int i = get_global_id(0);
int j = get_global_id(1);
gray[i, j] = (r[i, j] + g[i, j] + b[i, j])/ 3;
}
"""
gpu_program_source = pyopencl.Program(ctx, program_source)
gpu_program = gpu_program_source.build()
program_kernel_names = gpu_program.get_info(pyopencl.program_info.KERNEL_NAMES)
print(program_kernel_names)

queue = pyopencl.CommandQueue(ctx)

r_buf = pyopencl.Buffer(ctx, pyopencl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY |             
pyopencl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=r)
g_buf = pyopencl.Buffer(ctx, pyopencl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY | 
pyopencl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=g)
b_buf = pyopencl.Buffer(ctx, pyopencl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY |     
pyopencl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=b)
gray_buf = pyopencl.Buffer(ctx, pyopencl.mem_flags.WRITE_ONLY, r.nbytes)

gpu_program.rgb2gray(queue, r.shape, None, r_buf, g_buf, b_buf, gray_buf)

pyopencl.enqueue_copy(queue, gray, gray_buf)


plt.imshow(gray)
plt.show()

gray = np.uint8(gray)

imread.imsave('gigapixel_gray.jpg', gray)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the `array[x,y]` notation, then try Numba instead of PyOpenCL. Numba converts Python function's bytecode into OpenCL kernels.

PyOpenCL is only a wrapper over OpenCL API so it compiles the given kernel code for C or C++ languages directly. So you need to index like this:

```
int i = get_global_id(0);
int j = get_global_id(1);
gray[i][j] = (r[i][j] + g[i][j] + b[i][j])/ 3;
```

If you want to see the errors produced at any stage(kernel compiling, buffer copying, etc), you need to catch exceptions of Python because PyOpenCL binds OpenCL-errors to Python exceptions. You should check them like this:

```
try:
  your_opencl_accelerated_function()
except:
  print("Something didn't work")
```

Comment: using your changes throws 3 errors and says r, g, b is not any of these > array, pointer, vector
Later I fixed it by flattening the arrays from to 2d to 1d 
and made the kernel as g[i]= ( r[i] +g[i] +b[i] ) / 3
and then reshaped the 1d gray to original image shape
made a benchmark with cpu vs openCL vs numba
and numba seemed to be the fastest
@njit
def rgb2gray(r, g, b, gray_):
    for i in range(r.shape[0]):
        for j in range(r.shape[1]):
            gray_[i, j] = (r[i, j] + g[i, j] + b[i, j]) / 3
    return gray_
I dont have Nvidia, so numba is probably using my CPU

Comment: https://github.com/rvxfahim/opencl_vs_cpu_vs_numba

Comment: There is also numba for amd graphics cards it was called roc. But that kernel is not heavy enough to benefit from a gpu. Data copying from pcie has latency.